# How to create a global filter in able to support @JsonFilter annotated POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

i'm facing a problem during creating a simple filter using `SimpleFilterProvider`

```
Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'customerFilter'; no FilterProvider configured
```

My code is :

```
SimpleFilterProvider simpleFilterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false);
FilterProvider filters =simpleFilterProvider.addFilter("customerFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames)); 
ObjectWriter writer=null;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
writer=mapper.writer();
String dtoAsString = writer.writeValueAsString(customer);
```

My POJO is **Customer**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonFilter("customerFilter") 
public class Customer {

    public Customer() {

    }

    public Customer(String customerId,String phoneNumber) {

        this.customerId=customerId;
        this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * customer identifier
     */
    @JsonPropertyDescription("customer identifier")
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private String customerId;

    /**
     * customer phone number
     */
    @JsonPropertyDescription("customer phone number")
    @JsonProperty("phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
....
```

Any help please considering that my app is an SpringBoot app !

Comment: Maybe your  Customer class is not scanned by spring at startup. Check your packages related to Application.java entry point used in spring boot apps.

Comment: Take a look at this response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653444/hide-some-fields-dynamically-before-marshalling-java-to-json/53209051#53209051

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you serialize your `Customer` object (e.g. in `RestController`) manually (exactly as you coded) it works fine (see method `getManual` below). However relying on Spring object mapper requires registering additional filter provider (without it method `getAuto` fails):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    private static final Set<String> ignorableFieldNames= new HashSet<>();

    static {
        ignorableFieldNames.add("customerId");
    }

    @RequestMapping("auto")
    public Customer getAuto() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new Customer("123", "456");
    }

    @RequestMapping("manual")
    public String getManual() throws JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleFilterProvider simpleFilterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false);
        FilterProvider filters = simpleFilterProvider.addFilter("customerFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames));

        ObjectWriter writer = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
        writer = mapper.writer();

        Customer customer = new Customer("123", "456");
        String dtoAsString = writer.writeValueAsString(customer);
        return dtoAsString;
    }
}
```

Registering your custom filter:

```
@Component
public class CustomerFilterConfig {
    private static final Set<String> ignorableFieldNames = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        ignorableFieldNames.add("phoneNumber");
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleFilterProvider simpleFilterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().setFailOnUnknownId(false);
        FilterProvider filters = simpleFilterProvider.addFilter("customerFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(ignorableFieldNames));
        objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filters);

        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }    
}
```

Comment: thanks, its work, but if i haven't no field to filter, how can i disable the filter ?

Comment: Like applying filter conditionally? Similar this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603581/using-conditions-to-dynamically-exclude-pojo-property-in-jackson-json-serializat ?